# ROWTYPE definition in pl/sql

Tags: plsql, cursor, procedure, records

I have written a PL/SQL Procedure which compares data between two tables and print the difference if any, but the twist is the table names to the procedure is dynamic. Here is the procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE compareTables(
tabA IN VARCHAR2, tabB IN VARCHAR2) AS
    cur_tab_name USER_TABLES%ROWTYPE;
    lv_sql varchar2(4000);
    lv_sql2 varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
--SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO cur_tab_name FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = tabA;
lv_sql2 := 'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = :b_tabA';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_sql2 INTO cur_tab_name USING tabA;
    <<child>>
     DECLARE
         TYPE cursor_ref IS REF CURSOR;
         cur_comp_result cursor_ref;
         rec_comp_result cur_tab_name.TABLE_NAME%rowtype;
     BEGIN
          lv_sql := 'SELECT * FROM '||tabA||' MINUS SELECT * FROM '||tabB;
          OPEN cur_comp_result FOR lv_sql;
        LOOP
            FETCH cur_comp_result INTO rec_comp_result;
            EXIT WHEN cur_comp_result%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_comp_result.empid || '' || rec_comp_result.name);
        END LOOP;
          CLOSE cur_comp_result;
     Exception 
        When others then 
                dbms_output.put_line('The Problem is '||sqlerrm); 

     END;
END compareTables;
```

Now the problem is when I compile this procedure I am getting the following error

```
Error at line 14: PLS-00310: with %ROWTYPE attribute, 'CUR_TAB_NAME.TABLE_NAME' must   name a table, cursor or cursor-variable
```

line 14:rec_comp_result cur_tab_name.TABLE_NAME%rowtype;

how will I solve it?

*NB: I don't have oracle installed in my system. I am using [Oracle Apex Online tool](http://apex.oracle.com/) which uses
 Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 and
 PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: In your code, which line is 31?

Comment: Last line of the procedure

Comment: Try to remove the ̉`<<parent>>`, but for sure remove the `declare` at the begining.

Comment: I removed the both, but still some error is showing, please see the comment in EvilTeach's answer.

Comment: Update your post, put the new code , error message and the line.

Answer (score 2):

As a test, go to the last line, and after the semicolon, hit enter.
I know that Pro*C in particular will gag without a line terminator at the end of the file.
You may be encounting that issue.

Outside the scope of your question consider

```
SELECT columns 
FROM TABLE1

MINUS

SELECT columns
FROM TABLE2
```

and

```
SELECT columns
FROM TABLE2

MINUS

SELECT columns
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: Thanks @EvilTeach, that error is not showing now and I also removed <<parent>> and declare in the beginning as suggested by Plouf, but now the error showing is

Error at line 14: PLS-00310: with %ROWTYPE attribute, 'CUR_TAB_NAME.TABLE_NAME' must name a table, cursor or cursor-variable

line 14:rec_comp_result cur_tab_name.TABLE_NAME%rowtype;

I know, cur_tab_name.TABLE_NAME is the table name of data type varchar2, but if I put 
rec_comp_result cur_tab_name%rowtype;
where cur_tab_name is a cursor variable, then it shows the error

Comment: Error at line 14: PLS-00310: with %ROWTYPE attribute, 'CUR_TAB_NAME.TABLE_NAME' must name a table, cursor or cursor-variable
line 14:rec_comp_result cur_tab_name.TABLE_NAME%rowtype;
What can be the solution? 
Also, thanks for your suggestion, but my requirement is to get A-B. not (A-B) U (B-A)

Comment: I think, rec_comp_result is not properly declared and cur_tab_name is not a cursor variable, but how the problem will be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Use: `cur_tab_name.table_name`. The variable `CUR_TAB_NAME`is of type `USER_TABLE%ROWTYPE`, thus it has several fields.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I have used cur_tab_name.table_name%rowtype in line 14. What should I use?